# database - Inner join with 3 tables in mysql issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing a favorite system which allow users to save the posts to their page.

The tables I'm using  are:

`saved_posts` table  which contain 3 columns (``` painned_id``user_id``post_id ```)

`users` which contain (`user_id`, `frist_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `user_website`, `user_avatar`)

Finally `posts` table (`post_id`, `user_id`, `post_author`, `category_id`, `post_date`, `post_image`, `post_avatar`, `user_website`, `post_keywords`, `post_content`)

The my sql code I'm using to get the saved posrt

```
 SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN saved_posts
  ON saved_posts.post_id =
  posts.post_id INNER JOIN users on saved_posts.user_id = users.user_id WHERE
  saved_posts.user_id  =  users.user_id AND  saved_posts.post_id = posts.post_id
```

The problem is that the saved posts from one user appears for other user  as if they saved them as well.

Comment: Try this query: "SELECT * FROM saved_posts INNER JOIN posts  ON saved_posts.post_id  = posts.post_id INNER JOIN users on   saved_posts.user_id = users.user_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you filter your answer with a `WHERE` condition? Otherwise it is just finding all posts that any user shared EVER.

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
INNER JOIN saved_posts  
ON saved_posts.post_id  = posts.post_id
INNER JOIN users 
ON saved_posts.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.user_id = :wanted_user_id
```

Don't forget to bind `wanted_user_id`.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote this condition but it didn't work "SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN saved_posts
ON saved_posts.post_id = posts.post_id INNER JOIN users on saved_posts.user_id = users.user_id WHERE  saved_posts.user_id  =  users.user_id AND  saved_posts.post_id = posts.post_id  "

Comment: I used session to get the user Id Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, the task is to select all the posts which of the users

```
SELECT * FROM posts p 
    INNER JOIN saved_posts sp ON p.post_id  = sp.post_id 
            and sp.user_id = u.user_id
    INNER JOIN users u on p.user_id = u.user_id
```